# Selecting a database from a variable

Tags: sql

So I have two databases that have no relationship between them. The first one is where my dbo.Clients exists and  has a column of the database name of the second db . My thought was to select the dbName from the Clients then use that variable to select data from the second database. 
The query doesnt run can some one shed a little light? Thanks.

```
    @dbName varchar(50) OUTPUT,
@clientID varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * FROM sql02.iproconfig4.dbo.Clients 
    SET @dbName = (SELECT Clients.ClientDatabase FROM sql02.iproconfig4.dbo.Clients WHERE ClientID = @clientID) 
    SELECT * FROM sql02.@dbName.dbo.Discovery   
END
```

Comment: Try searching: Query two tables from different schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) to accomplish this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM sql02.' + @dbName + '.dbo.Discovery'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This almost works, although it gives me an Invalid object name 'iproconfig4_14112_0007.dbo.Discovery'. what does that mean?

Comment: Do you have a database called `iproconfig4_14112_0007` on a server called `sql02`?

Comment: It means it can't find the object. Therefore either server, database, schema or table don't exist.